# definition of the Fourier transform of function on the sphere

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, definition, spherical-harmonics

Let $f: S^{n-1}\longrightarrow R^n$ be  even continuous function.

What is the Fourier transform of $f$?

Comment: Do you know the definition of the Fourier transform on a locally compact Abelian group?

Comment: Do you know the action of $SO(3)$ on $S^2$? Peter-Weyl theorem?

Comment: No, I am not familiar wiht those things. My background is functional analysis, but not  harmonic analysis...

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality for details. This *is* a functional analysis topic; the way I see it. For a locally compact Abelian group $G$, the Fourier transform is the Gelfand transform on the group algebra of $G$.

Comment: @ Christopher A. Wong: Thank you.

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk did you mean the result of the action of $SO(3)$ on $S²$ is the Fourier transform on the sphere? For what I know, it's indeed the rotation of the Riemann sphere in [Möbius transformation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JX3VmDgiFnY). However it's just a part of it, while the whole Möbius transform is more intuitive. Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 2):

One way of defining the Fourier transform over the $n-$dimensional sphere, is to define it over $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ and use the Cayley transform to map the operator to $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. If we do this,
then we define the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}$ of an $L^2-$integrable $f$ over $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ with respect to the Clifford algebra $A_n$ as

\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{F}_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}(f)(u)=\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}H_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}(x,u)f(x)d\sigma(x)
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
H_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}=c(n)J(\psi,u)e^{-i\langle \psi(x),\psi(u)\rangle}\overline{J}(\psi,x).
\end{equation*}
Here, $d\sigma$ is the respective measure, $c(n)$ is a normalisation constant, and $\psi$ is the inverse of the Cayley transformation.

Note: When we are doing any kind of harmonic analysis over the sphere, we need to introduce spherical harmonics.

Comment: Could you please define what the function $J$ is?